# Java spring/HTML setting modelattribute to fixed string when clicking on an image

Tags: java, html, image, forms, spring

Hi i'm a newbie in html and the spring framework :/

I wish to set the value in the modelAttribute to a fixed string 
for example, if you click on the first image, the value would be "receipt".
If you would click on the second image, the value of the attribute would be "shoppinglist"

```
<form:form method="POST" action="index.htm" modelAttribute="itemGroup" inputpath="value">

        <input type="image"  img src="Images/receipt.png"      height="150px" width="180px"  alt="Submit" />
        <input type="image"  img src="Images/shoppinglist.png" height="150px" width="180px"  alt="Submit" ">
        <input type="image"  img src="Images/voucher.png"      height="150px" width="180px"  alt="Submit" >
        <input type="image"  img src="Images/card.png"         height="150px" width="180px"  alt="Submit" />

</form:form>
```

in the HomeController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/index"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showHomePage(Model model) 
{
model.addAttribute("itemGroup", new ItemGroup());
return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = {"/index"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute("itemGroup") ItemGroup itemGroup, Model model)
{
model.addAttribute("itemGroupImage",itemGroupService.showJobGroupImage(itemGroup.getValue()));
return "itemGroupView";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add *value* attribute for every input. For your example it would be

```
<input type="image"  img src="Images/receipt.png"    value="receipt"  height="150px" width="180px"  alt="Submit" />
<input type="image"  img src="Images/shoppinglist.png" value="shoppinglist" height="150px" width="180px"  alt="Submit" ">
```

Comment: i've tried that already but in the post method, the value of the object is still null

Comment: the itemGroup object, which has the atttribute value (=String)

Comment: <form:form method="POST" action="index.htm" modelAttribute="itemGroup">
<form:input path="value" type="hidden" value="receipts" />
<input type="image" src="Images/receipt.png" height="150px" width="180px"  alt="Submit">
</form:form>